# Android: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException': No tests found

Tags: testing, gradle, android-studio, classnotfoundexception, android-instrumentation

I try to run a instrumentation test via "gradlew connectedAndroidTest". I get following error:

```
Tests on GT-I9305 - 4.3 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[GT-I9305 - 4.3] FAILED 
No tests found.                              
:mobile:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
```

This is the output with --stacktrace option:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mobile:connectedAndroidTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/myapp/mobile/build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.runTests(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.groovy:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >

    <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myapp"
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/androidTest')
        }
        test {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
configurations {
    apt
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

ext {
    daggerVersion = '1.2.2';
    androidAnnotationsVersion = '3.2';
    robobindingVersion = '0.8.9';
    jodatimeVersion = '2.5.1';
    ormliteVersion = '4.48';
    ottoVersion = '1.3.5';
    commonsioVersion = '2.0.1';
    playservicesVersion = '6.1.71';
    supportv4Version = '21.0.2';
    javaxinjectVersion = '1';
    junitVersion = '4.11';
    robolectricVersion = '2.4';
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'

    apt "org.robobinding:codegen:$robobindingVersion"
    compile("org.robobinding:robobinding:$robobindingVersion:with-dependencies") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':javamail')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${playservicesVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportv4Version}"
    compile "com.squareup:otto:${ottoVersion}"
    compile "javax.inject:javax.inject:${javaxinjectVersion}"
    compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:${ormliteVersion}"
    compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:${ormliteVersion}"
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: "${commonsioVersion}"
    compile "net.danlew:android.joda:${jodatimeVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}


android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/generated/source/apt/${variant.dirName}")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

My **test class**:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void testSomething() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The answer I posted before seemed to only fix it for 5.0 devices, I added how I resolved fixing it for pre-5.0 devices after I found out it didn't work on those. Seemed you were also running 4.3

Comment: @Lauw I have this problem too. I could not run Espresso 2 tests on any device or emulator with API < 21.

Comment: Check out the edit I made to the original answer, that should solve it for devices with API < 21.

Comment: @Lauw That wasn't the only cause for me, but it was the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

I just found myself with the same problem, and resolved it by updating to espresso 2.0

Replace the testInstrumentationRunner in your build.gradle file

```
 testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner
```

to

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

and update the new dependencies to 2.0

```
androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
```

to

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

You also have to change the namespace in your tests, but you will notice when running them.

Full explanation:
https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

**Edit:**

Seems I was too soon in answering, the answer I posted only fixed it on 5.0 devices. Below is what fixed it on older devices:

Exclude javax.inject from the new dependency by changing:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

to

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
```

source:
[Dagger code giving NoClassDefFoundError when Espresso Tests are run, normal run works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641965/dagger-code-giving-noclassdeffounderror-when-espresso-tests-are-run-normal-run)

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 6):

I got this problem when I wrote a test in **Kotlin** and used spaces in the method name. It crashes with the error message:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

In Android Studio:
`No tests where found`

**Broken Test:**
spaces in method names, doesn't work on Android

```
class RandomTest {

    @Test
    fun `do not use spaces it will not work on Android devices or emulators`() {
        assertThat(2 + 2).isEqualTo(4)
    }
}
```

**Solution:**
removed spaces, everything compiles normally

```
class RandomTest {

    @Test
    fun write_method_names_java6_compatible_without_spaces() {
        assertThat(2 + 2).isEqualTo(4)
    }
}
```

This could happen because I disabled the Inspection "Illegal Android Identifier" so it doesn't annoy me when writing JVM tests

Answer (score 5):

The problem for me was adding the test in Kotlin, but not having Kotlin support previously. So I need to put in to my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Then delete the test configuration and add it again.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue when after some refactoring I tried to run test from the console.

The solution was to fix the AndroidManifest.xml, as it contained references to no longer existing activities and other classes.

Sure thing, the project will compile with a bad manifest, but when you try to run it, the device won't find the defined classes. Thus the ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue. In my project there were multiple modules and multidex was enabled. For me the problem was in one particular module multidex enable option (multiDexEnabled true) was missing.

In main module (app) the build.gradle was like following:

```
...
multiDexEnabled true
testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
...
```

In another module (on which app is dependent on), the build.gradle was missing the line "multiDexEnabled true". Adding this line resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer from [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002212/test-running-failed-unable-to-find-instrumentation-info-for-componentinfo/40783632#40783632).

This is what I noticed in my project, in my app(main) module build.gradle I had the following buildType configuration

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        mock {
            initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        }
    }
testBuildType "mock"
```

When I used **AndroidJUnitRunner** as the test runner(both from Android Studio) and as *testInstrumentationRunner* in build.gradle, tests ran without hitch.

In a submodule that had *multiDexEnabled true* as *defaultConfig*

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    ....
}
```

I ran into the problem of

```
Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for:{mypackage.x.y/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"}
```

when I specified **AndroidJUnitRunner** in IDE and the submodule build.gradle. And this was fixed by specifying **MultiDexTestRunner** as the test runner in IDE/build.gradle.

> To summarize, Use **MultiDexTestRunner** to run tests when *multiDexEnabled true* is specified in build.gradle, else use **AndroidJUnitRunner** as the test runner.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by turning off the Proguard.